# Must use destructuring props assignment

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint

I'm using Eslint in my React Native project, and in this code:

```
export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.bootstrapAsync();
  }

  bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Eslint given a warning: "Must use destructuring props assignment". I've tried to change assignment to

```
const navigation = this.props;
navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
```

But it gives an error: "undefined is not an object"

**EDIT:** 
changed the constructor to:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.bootstrapAsync(props);
  }
```

now code runs without errors

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
```

Or if you want to go one lever deeper:

```
const { navigation: { navigate } } = this.props;
navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
```

But in that case the navigation object should be defined. Although it is possible to give a default value for destructuring objects.

E.g.

```
const { navigation: { navigate } = {} } = this.props;
```

Now navigation will be an empty object if it's undefined.

Comment: Is it ok to use instead: `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`?

Comment: Yes, you can deconstruct every object. `this.props` and `this.props.navigation` are both objects, so you can apply that structure to both of them.

Comment: I finally figured out what is wrong. I didn't pass props to the constructor, but tried to call `this.bootstrapAsync();` I added props, and now this part of code looks like 
`constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.bootstrapAsync(props);
  }` 
and works well

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the navigate function, then as Milore said, the best way of achieving what you'd like is:

`const {navigate} = this.props.navigation`

However, if you need to destructure other properties of navigation, you can use:

`const {navigation} = this.props`

Or destructure as Hespen recommended.

More on destructuring: [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)  [JS Info](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment)